# how to access assets/image from the controller in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, sails.js

I want to create an image processing library. I can now successfully upload my images into the assets/image directory in my server. Now, I would like to call that image from my controller so that i can edit or try the image processing filters.

For eg.

```
   var img = "assets/image/loc.jpg"
   var pixels = img.getPixels.
```

However, I could not find a way to get the image from the controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails.js is a framework built around node.js, so you have access to the File System through

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Documentation here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html.

You'll probably do something like

```
fs.readFile('assets/image/loc.jpg', function (err, data) {
  //do whatever you want with your img 'data'
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback